# Dropdown menu to filter results in php get all results from sql

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

I have this drop down:

```
<select class="w-select filterdropdown" id="Tipo-de-cocina" name="tipofiltro" data-name="Tipo de cocina">
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['tipofiltro'])) {
        echo '<option value="' .$filtrocuisine.  '"> '  .$filtrocuisine. "</option>";

    } else {
        echo '<option value="Todos los tipos">Todos los tipos</option>';
    }

?>


              <option value="Japonesa">Japonesa</option>
              <option value="Mexicana">Mexicana</option>
              <option value="India">India</option>
              <option value="Mediterranea">Mediterranea</option>
              <option value="Italiana">Italiana</option>
              <option value="Americana">Americana</option>
              <option value="Asiatica">Asiatica</option>
              <option value="Thai">Thai</option>
              <option value="China">China</option>
              <option value="Francesa">Francesa</option>
              <option value="Turca">Turca</option>
              <option value="Latina">Latina</option>
              <option value="Africana">Africana</option>
              <option value="Griega">Griega</option>
              <option value="Arabe">Arabe</option>


            </select>
```

How can i make that when the user selects the field "Todos los tipos" my sql query returns all types? This is the sql behind:

```
if (isset($_GET['preciofiltro']) OR isset($_GET['preciofiltro'])) {
    $filtroprecio = $_GET['preciofiltro'];
    $filtrocuisine = $_GET['tipofiltro'];

    $sql = "SELECT Meals.Meal_ID, Meals.Name, Price, Cooks.Cook_ID 
            FROM Meals 
               INNER JOIN Cooks ON Cooks.Cook_ID = Meals.Cook_ID 
            WHERE Cooks.Area = '$area' 
              AND Meals.Capacity > 0 
              AND Meals.Price < '$filtroprecio' 
              AND Meals.Type = '$filtrocuisine'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Basically I would need something such as "AND Meals.Type = any"

Cheers!

Comment: on select of one option, you want to fetch value from database??

Comment: Do you want the certain query records to be fetched (shown) that are in the database?

Comment: so, what's not working with the query you're using presently?

Comment: *btw*, this `if (isset($_GET['preciofiltro']) OR isset($_GET['preciofiltro']))` doesn't make sense. You may have meant to use `if (isset($_GET['preciofiltro']) OR !empty($_GET['preciofiltro']))`. or `if (isset($_GET['preciofiltro']) OR isset($_GET['tipofiltro']))` . Or... well you know what I mean ;-)

Comment: `AND|OR Meals.Type LIKE '%$filtrocuisine%'";`, there, *give that a whirl*. You can jump in here anytime, don't be shy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are simpler methods but without rewriting everything the simple answer is that if the user selects `Todos los tipos` from the dropdown what you actually want to do is remove this selection criteria `AND Meals.Type = '$filtrocuisine'` from the query completely i.e. you no longer limit the query with that criteria.

So change your script like this :-

I am of course assuming that you have taken data from the `$_GET` array, validated it, and cleansed it before we get to this code.

```
if (isset($_GET['preciofiltro']) OR isset($_GET['preciofiltro'])) {
    $filtroprecio = $_GET['preciofiltro'];
    $filtrocuisine = $_GET['tipofiltro'];

$sql = "SELECT Meals.Meal_ID, Meals.Name, Price, Cooks.Cook_ID 
        FROM Meals 
           INNER JOIN Cooks ON Cooks.Cook_ID = Meals.Cook_ID 
        WHERE Cooks.Area = '$area' 
          AND Meals.Capacity > 0 
          AND Meals.Price < '$filtroprecio'";

if ( isset($filtrocuisine) && $filtrocuisine == 'Todos los tipos' ) {
    $sql .= " AND Meals.Type = '$filtrocuisine'";
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: I think the OP's busy in *"la cucina"*.